# Create separate PDF's (one page per PDF) C# ItextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

A long time ago, an application was created with which e-tickets could be sold online.

The e-tickets are in PDF format.

The software uses an old library (`itextsharp.dll`) but it still works perfectly.

What happens now when someone buys 4 tickets, for example, is that the system creates 1 PDF file (with 4 pages) and sends it as an attachment by e-mail.

What I now want is for the system to create 4 separate PDF files and send them as 4 attachments.

As I can see now, the PDF is placed in a `MemoryStream` and this `MemoryStream` (1 PDF with 4 pages) is then sent as an attachment. And this works well!

Is it possible to put 4 separate PDF objects into a `MemoryStream` and then send them as an attachment? So that the recipient receives 4 separate PDF files?

Naturally, it is impossible to predict in advance how many e-tickets someone will buy.

Below is a piece of C# code that now ensures that all pages end up in 1 PDF.

Do you have the solution for me?

```
PhonepageBytes = Phonestream.ToArray();
PhonepagesAll.Add(PhonepageBytes);
}

MemoryStream Phonetickets = new MemoryStream();

Document Phonedoc = new Document();

PdfSmartCopy Phonecopy = new PdfSmartCopy(Phonedoc, Phonetickets);

Phonedoc.Open();
Phonedoc.OpenDocument();

foreach (var b in PhonepagesAll)
{
    Phonedoc.NewPage();
    Phonecopy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(new PdfReader(b), 1));
    // Create a new output PDF document (and save it into memorystream)
}

Phonecopy.CloseStream = false;
Phonecopy.Close();

SendTickets(fullName, emailAddress, Phonetickets);
```

I really don't have a clue. :-(

The code is working perfect to create 1 PDF with an e-ticket on each page. I want a separate PDF for each e-ticket and send all those PDFs as attachment.

Comment: A MemoryStream is just a stream.  I doesn't know anything about PDFs or attachments.  The receiver would have to know how to separate the tickets.

Comment: To create separate files, use separate streams and documents. Add each file as a separate attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code.

```
List<MemoryStream> ticketStreams = new List<MemoryStream>();

foreach (var ticketData in PhonepagesAll)
{
    MemoryStream ticketStream = new MemoryStream();

    Document ticketDoc = new Document();
    PdfSmartCopy ticketCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(ticketDoc, ticketStream);

    ticketDoc.Open();
    ticketDoc.OpenDocument();

    ticketDoc.NewPage();
    ticketCopy.AddPage(new PdfReader(ticketData));

    ticketCopy.CloseStream = false;
    ticketCopy.Close();

    // Add the ticket MemoryStream to the list
    ticketStreams.Add(ticketStream);
}

SendTicket(emailAddress, ticketStreams)
```

```
void SendTicket(string emailAddress, List<MemoryStream> ticketStreams)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("your@email.com");
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailAddress));
    mail.Subject = "Your Tickets";

    // Attach all the ticket MemoryStreams to the email
    int ticketNo = 0;
    foreach (var ticketStream in ticketStreams)
    {
        ticketNo++;
        ticketStream.Position = 0; // Reset stream position to start
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(ticketStream, $"Ticket-{ticketNo}.pdf");
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    }

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("your_smtp_server");
    smtpClient.Send(mail);
}
```

The above code will create separate `MemoryStreams` for each e-ticket, add them to a list, and then attach each `MemoryStream` as a separate attachment to a single email.
Here I used an `SMTP` client to send the email with all the attached tickets, you need to implement your email sending logic.

Comment: Thanks Amit, this solution does exactly what I want! ❤️